# Calculating average of set range around max value of panda series

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate an average (+/- 3 rows) around the max value in different panda (9 total pandas in a dictionary) columns (T1,T2,T3) that look like this:

```
    Depth      T1      T2      T3  Ch
0       0  0.0045  0.0025  0.0045   1
1       5  0.0000 -0.0030 -0.0010   1
2      10 -0.0035 -0.0045 -0.0005   1
3      15 -0.0020 -0.0030 -0.0030   1
4      20  0.0005 -0.0005  0.0015   1
5      25 -0.0015 -0.0015  0.0005   1
```

I know that some of the columns may have their max value at the beginning of the top of the column and I will get the index out of bounds error, so I decided to just skip those columns. Here is my attempted code to calculate the specific average range for pandas in the dictionary:

```
for df in channels.values():
    ROI_avgs = []
    for column in df[['T1', 'T2','T3']]:
            min = (df[[column]].idxmax() - 3)
            max = (df[[column]].idxmax() + 3)
            #append mean of +/- 3 rows of max in column to roi list only if min is in range
            if (min - 3 <= df[[column]].idxmax() - 3 ) & (max + 3 >= df[[column]].idxmax() + 3):
                 ROI_avgs.append(df[[column]].iloc[[min,max]].mean(axis=0))
            else:
                 ROI_avgs.append(math.nan)
    
    df.loc[len(ROI_avgs)] = ROI_avgs
```

When I run this I get the error, " The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is talking about this line:

```
if (min - 3 <= df[[column]].idxmax() - 3 ) & (max + 3 >= df[[column]].idxmax() + 3):
```

comparing a value to a series yield a series of dtype bool, maybe what you want is this:

```
if min >= 0 and max < len(df):
```